# How to convert images in directory to np array

Tags: python, image-processing, image-resizing, numpy-ndarray

I have images stored in the directory:

```
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import Image
import os, shutil
from os import listdir
## Image Resizing
from PIL import Image

# load and display an image with Matplotlib
from matplotlib import image
from matplotlib import pyplot


# Image folder
images_dir = Path('C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\\images').expanduser()
images_dir

dim = (400, 300)

# Resizing all the images to same dimension
X_image_train = []
for fname in listdir(images_dir):
    fpath = os.path.join(images_dir, fname)
    im = Image.open(fpath)
    im_resized = im.resize(dim)
    X_image_train.append(im_resized)

## Converting the image to numpy array
X_image_array=[]
for x in range(len(X_image_train)):
    X_image=np.array(X_image_train[x],dtype='uint8')
    X_image_array.append(X_image)

# Checking the size of a single image
X_image_array[0].shape
> (300, 400, 3)

 # Checking the size of a single image
    X_image_array[15].shape
    > (300, 400, 3)
```

I want to convert 'X_image_array' to a tensor with following dim:

```
(2000,300, 400, 3)
```

where 2000 is the number of samples in the 'images' folder.

Need help here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.stack()` function

```
np.stack(X_image_array)
```

Comment: Not working, getting this error: ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

Comment: So your images are of different shape. Why do you want to have images of different shape in a numpy array?

Comment: I am resizing them into (400,300) using `im_resized = im.resize(dim)` to make them of same shape. Confused why i am getting this error.

Comment: To check if there are images which were not resized properly, i added 
`assert X_image.shape == (300,400,3), "img %s has shape %r" % (fname, X_image.shape)`  in the loop. I got the error: `AssertionError: img 653142_Katabatik_Fisherman.jpg has shape (300, 400)`....

Is there a way to force all the images to (300,400,3) shape as the above code is not resizing it properly.

Comment: Probably that is a gray image. Check